# Core Data - Handling dynamic property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I need a way to handle dynamic properties in an `NSManagedObject` subclass. What I do now is to check if an object's `date` (NSDate class) property is passed by `[NSDate now]`. If that date is property is passed then the object is flagged as `overdue`.

So whenever I need to show if an object is overdue I need to do the comparison above. So this property can switch states being overdue and not being overdue. It seems kind of wrong to do this check all the time. Is there some way to do this automagically? I. e. every time I fetch the objects from the database Core Data will perform this above method for me?

Comment: You should never persist derived properties along with the data from which they are derived: what looked like "not overdue" at the time of a fetch may become overdue one second later, but your program will have no idea.

Comment: So every time I need to check if an object is overdue I need to manually perform my logic? I thought Core Data had some way of saving it as a "smart" property (like "smart" folders in OS X).

Comment: I do not know of a way to *implement* this in the Core Data way, but inside the implementation the check should be performed every time you make a call to check the overdue status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you are looking for by using NSManagedObject subclasses, and transient attributes.

The dynamic property that you want can be achieved by making a 'transient' attribute. You can make an attribute transient by checking the transient option. Transient attributes are not persisted to the local store.

Create a NSManagedObject subclass for your entity by using the New File wizard, it's located under the category 'Core Data'.

When the class is created, just create a getter method for your dynamic property to return what you want.

Now you can use this as normal during your fetch requests.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to persist the status of overdue, since it depends on a variable which is always changing. If you need to do something based on the next overdue object, just fetch the data that is not overdue, sort it by date, and find the next one to be overdue. Then, you can do a dispatch_after to do whatever your app does when a record goes overdue.